# jetty 7 continuations

Tags: java, jetty, continuations

i'm using jetty-7.4.1.v20110513 and servlet-api-2.5

i tried to use continations in the following servlet.

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;
 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

 import org.eclipse.jetty.continuation.*;



public class cs extends HttpServlet {

public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
throws java.io.IOException {

String reqId = req.getParameter("id");

Continuation cc = ContinuationSupport.getContinuation(req);

res.setContentType("text/plain");
res.getWriter().println("Request: "+reqId+"\tstart:\t"+new Date());
res.getWriter().flush();

cc.setTimeout(2000);
cc.suspend();

res.getWriter().println("Request: "+reqId+"\tend:\t"+new Date());
cc.complete();
}
}
```

I'm expecting a 2 sec delay but when i run the servlet from browser i'm getting output as following without any delay:

```
Request: null   start:  Sat May 21 15:25:02 IST 2011
Request: null   end:    Sat May 21 15:25:02 IST 2011
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the continuations api. the following code worked for me.thanks for your support guys.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.jetty.continuation.*;

public class cs extends HttpServlet {

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
      throws java.io.IOException {

    String reqId = req.getParameter("id");

    Continuation cc = ContinuationSupport.getContinuation(req);

    res.setContentType("text/plain");
    res.getWriter().println("Request: " + reqId + "\tstart:\t" + new Date());
    res.getWriter().flush();

    cc.setTimeout(2000);
    cc.suspend();

    res.getWriter().println("Request: " + reqId + "\tend:\t" + new Date());
    if (cc.isInitial() != true) {
      cc.complete();
    }
  }
}
```

output:

```
Request: null   start:  Sat May 21 15:25:02 IST 2011
Request: null   end:    Sat May 21 15:25:02 IST 2011
Request: null   start:  Sat May 21 15:25:04 IST 2011
Request: null   end:    Sat May 21 15:25:04 IST 2011
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're reading this [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/j-jettydwr/index.html). A 2 seconds delay can be achieved using one of these ways:

- Either add `Thread.sleep(2000)` before the second `res.getWriter().println()`.
- Or remove `Continuation.complete()` call that will make continuation wait for the maximum time specified in `Continuation.setTimeout()`. What happens now is that you notify **immediately** that your "calculation" is done (via calling `cc.complete()`)